# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'images\x08ackground.jpg'

Tags: python, debugging, path, pycharm

The code:

```
from tkinter import*
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Login_System:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root=root
        self.root.title("Login System")
        self.root.geometry("1350x700+0+0")
        
        img = Image.open('images\background.jpg')
        self.bg_icon=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

root=Tk()
obj=Login_System(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\PythonLoginSystem\login.py", line 15, in <module>
> obj=Login_System(root)
> File "c:\PythonLoginSystem\login.py", line 11, in **init**
> img = Image.open('images\background.jpg')
> File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line
> 3131, in open
> fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'images\x08ackground.jpg'

[/images path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzcsc.png)

I checked the image path and I didn't see anything wrong with it. I tried 'images/background.jpg', r'images\background.jpg', 'images\background.jpg', but none of them worked

Comment: `\b` is the escape sequence for backspace in strings, which Windows doesn't allow in filenames. Use a raw string, double the backslash, or use a forward slash.